# ApplyLinearForce to dynamic body causes NullPointerException/ Libgdx box2d

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, box2d

I am developing an Android game using the libgdx box2d library in Eclipse. In the game, there's a ball that falls after touching the start button. But I get a nullpointerexception when the ball contacts the dynamic body.

On contact I want to applyLinearForce to that dynamic body. But I keep getting nullpointerexception on contact of the ball and dynamic body.

ContactHandler class:

> public class ContactHandler implements ContactListener {

```
InputHandler input;

@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    if(contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData() == "do1" && contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData() == "ball"){
        System.out.println("beginContact");
        input = new InputHandler();
        input.getBody1().applyLinearImpulse(10, 0, 0, 0, true);
    }
}
```

InputHandler class:

public class InputHandler implements InputProcessor {

```
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private Ball ball;
private DragObject dragObject;

private boolean start = false;
private Vector3 touch = new Vector3();
private Vector3 dragTo = new Vector3();

public InputHandler(){

}

public InputHandler(OrthographicCamera camera, Ball ball,
        DragObject dragObject) {
    this.camera = camera;
    this.ball = ball;
    this.dragObject = dragObject;

}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    if (!start) {
        for (Body body : dragObject.getBody()) {
            if (touch.x > body.getPosition().x - dragObject.getWidth() - 1
                    && touch.x < body.getPosition().x
                            + dragObject.getWidth() + 1) {
                if (touch.y > body.getPosition().y - dragObject.getHeight()
                        - 1
                        && touch.y < body.getPosition().y
                                + dragObject.getHeight() + 1) {
                    dragTo.set(screenX, screenY, 0);
                    camera.unproject(dragTo);
                    body.setTransform(dragTo.x, dragTo.y, 0);
                    touch.set(screenX, screenY, 0);
                    camera.unproject(touch);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public Body getBody1(){
    return dragObject.getBody().get(0);
}
```

DragObject class:

```
public static Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>();
public static int count = 0;

public DragObject(){

}

public DragObject(World world, float x, float y, float width, float height) {
    this.world = world;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    initialize();

    body1 = world.createBody(bodyDef1);
    body1.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    body1.setUserData("do1");
    bodies.add(body1);

}

public Array<Body> getBody() {
    return bodies;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor for the input handler is wrong, these lines should be removed:

```
public InputHandler(){

}
```

Because when you call this constructor here:

```
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    if(contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData() == "do1" && contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData() == "ball"){
        System.out.println("beginContact");

        //You are using the wrong contructor, therefore body1 or dragObject is never initialised
        input = new InputHandler();
        //The null pointer exception is here, no body1 has been initialised yet
        input.getBody1().applyLinearImpulse(10, 0, 0, 0, true);
    }
```

You need to make the contructor match and create a new DragObject within the InputHandler class and as a side note it isn't very efficient initialising the class every time the body collides I am sure you can think of a better way to organise it.